# Avoid creating object based on constructor value c++

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, std

My code is auto generated during compile time, so I don't know which object will be created.

During run time I have to decide whether I need it or not,so I want to creating object only if some condition satisfied, otherwise don't create and object below is example

```
class A {
public:
    A(int type, int value):
      type_(type),value_(value) {
      if (type_ == 0) {
          /*Create an object of this class and put in array */
      } else {
        /*Don't create an object of this class*/
      }
    }
private:
    int type_;
    int value_;
}

A a1(0,100); // Create an object 
A a2(1,200); // Don't create an object
A a3(0,300); // Create an object

int main()
{
....
....  
// use the object that was create and present in array
}
```

Comment: why -1  ? please give reason so I don't repeat my mistake.

Comment: If you don't want to create an object, then simply don't create it - don't wait the constructor to say "oh crap, I shouldn't have create it !"

Comment: @Synxis my code is auto generated during compile time, so I don't know which object will be create. During run time I have to decide whether I need it or not.

Comment: Try to implement Factory Pattern (or some other creation pattern) and basing on arguments, create object on heap or return nullptr.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the constructors body it's too late, the instance is already created then.

Either throw an exception, or use a template and [sfinae](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to apply the restrictions at compile time.

---

Even better outsource the instances creation to a separate factory class, that acts on the condition. It can return a `nullptr` or otherwise empty smart pointer, to indicate the instance wasn't created.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can create this is from a static function. I would never use it like that, but if you really need it, you can do something like this.

```
class A {
public:
    static A* createAnObject(int type, int value)
    {
        if (type == 0)
            return new A(type, value);
        else
            return NULL;
    }
    ~A();

private:
    //Put constructur here so that will force programer to use your static function
    A(int type, int value):type_(type),value_(value){};

    int type_;
    int value_;
}
};

A* a1 = A::createAnObject(0,100); // Create an object 
A* a2 = A::createAnObject(1,200); // Don't create an object
A* a3 = A::createAnObject(0,300); // Create an object

int main()
{
    //Now you need always to verify if you pointer is not NULL before use it
    if(a1)
        a1->somefunction();
....
}
```

But I do not recommend this way, creating object with new force you to always delete them by yourself and if you are a new programmer sometimes you will forget that, and if you have a NULL pointer so sometimes you will not verify it and try to call a function and this will crash you application.

Comment: @CaptainWise Nonsense. This doesn't have to do with singletons, but ownership semantics.

Comment: @user2672165 Yes I deleted my comment, I understood that you talked about singleton, it was a misunderstanding here, now it undertand that you talk about smart pointers :-)

Comment: @user2672165 Yes returning a unique_ptr would be a better idea, but i think beginner should use the old way to understand what they are doing, using unique_ptr will do the job for them and they will never understand what happened.

Comment: You should not use `NULL` for null pointer. Before C++11 the correct way was simply `0`, now it is `nullptr`.

Comment: @Synxis Yes you are right, it's bad habits from job, i'm working in a company that develop embedded systems in Windows CE with C/C++ that use a SDKs that can be only installed and worked with Visual Studio 2008. After 2 year working with that, I think it make you forget the 21 century C++